# Meaning of topological vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, terminology, topological-vector-spaces

It is stronger than "being both topological space and vector space", right? Then how should I call the latter? (BTW, does the latter lose this default name because it does not have nice properties?)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Definition

Comment: It is not sufficient to have just a vector space which has a topology on it, the important theme is that both vector space structure and topological space should interact with each other; this is exactly why vector space operations have to be continuous.

Comment: I would go for "a vector space which carries some topology" and if you want to be very clear, you could add "(which need not be compatible with the linear structure of ???)"

Comment: The tag ([tag:terminology]) seems suitable here. I was a bit more hesitant about ([tag:topological-vector-spaces]) - since you're asking about something which is *not* a TVS. I'll leave it up to you whether or not to keep this tag.